# UIImage built from CMSampleBuffer not retained and causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, core-media

I am building a UIImage from a CMSampleBuffer.  From the main thread, I call a function to access the pixel data in the CMSampleBuffer and convert the YCbCr planes into an ABGR bitmap which I wrap in a UIImage.  I call the function from the main thread with:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {() -> Void in
    let image = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(frame)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        self.testView.image = image
        self.testView.hidden = false
    })
})
```

This maintains responsiveness of the UI and main thread as I would hope.  The function processing the buffer is:

```
func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage {

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)
    let lumaBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
    let chromaBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1)

    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

    let lumaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
    let chromaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1)
    let lumaBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(lumaBaseAddress)
    let chromaBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(chromaBaseAddress)

    var rgbaImage = [UInt8](count: 4*width*height, repeatedValue: 0)
    for var x = 0; x < width; x++ {
        for var y = 0; y < height; y++ {
            let lumaIndex = x+y*lumaBytesPerRow
            let chromaIndex = (y/2)*chromaBytesPerRow+(x/2)*2
            let yp = lumaBuffer[lumaIndex]
            let cb = chromaBuffer[chromaIndex]
            let cr = chromaBuffer[chromaIndex+1]

            let ri = Double(yp)                                + 1.402   * (Double(cr) - 128)
            let gi = Double(yp) - 0.34414 * (Double(cb) - 128) - 0.71414 * (Double(cr) - 128)
            let bi = Double(yp) + 1.772   * (Double(cb) - 128)

            let r = UInt8(min(max(ri,0), 255))
            let g = UInt8(min(max(gi,0), 255))
            let b = UInt8(min(max(bi,0), 255))
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4] = b
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4 + 1] = g
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4 + 2] = r
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4 + 3] = 255
        }
    }

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let dataProvider: CGDataProviderRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, rgbaImage, 4 * width * height, nil)!
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)
    let cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorSpace!, bitmapInfo, dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)!
    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer,0)

    return image
}
```

If I put a breakpoint just before the function returns, I can use "Quick Look" and see the image (and it is what I would expect).  However, once the function returns, I cannot use `image` anywhere else and Quick Look always fails.  If I attempt to set a UIImageView to the returned image, nothing in the UI changes:

```
testView.image = image \\The UIImageView does not update.
```

If I try to access the image in any other way (e.g., to attempt to save it to Parse), the code crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Again, if I save the image to Parse within the above function, it appears in the backend database as expected.

I have also tried calling the processing function without dispatching to global and main queues by calling the function directly.  The results are always the same.

I believe this is because the image is not retained.  I have tried defining both the image and CGImage context at the class and file level, but neither change the outcome.  I thought this would maintain a reference, but it apparently does not.  I am new enough to Swift that I clearly do not understand how ARC is working in this case.

I also believe there were a few times while debugging using Quick Look from within the function that the first time I clicked the Quick Look was "unavailable"... but waiting a few seconds and clicking again results in the image appearing.  Is it possible it is just taking longer for the data to be made available?  Perhaps GPU->CPU?  If so, how do I check/delay to avoid the crash?

How do I maintain a reference?  Is there a better way to handle the image created from the CMSampleBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way in which the CGImage is being created.  Using `dataProvider` and `CGImageCreate` is the specific issue:

```
let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, rgbaImage, 4 * width * height, nil)!
let cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorSpace!, bitmapInfo, dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)!
```

A working solution using `CGBitmapContextGetData` and `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` follows:

```
func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)
    let lumaBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
    let chromaBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1)

    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

    let lumaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
    let chromaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1)
    let lumaBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(lumaBaseAddress)
    let chromaBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(chromaBaseAddress)

    let contextBytesPerRow = Int(width) * 4
    let contextByteCount = contextBytesPerRow * Int(height)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let bitmapData = malloc(contextByteCount)
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, width, height, 8, contextBytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    let data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context)
    let rgbaImage = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(data)
    for var x = 0; x < width; x++ {
        for var y = 0; y < height; y++ {
            let lumaIndex = x+y*lumaBytesPerRow
            let chromaIndex = (y/2)*chromaBytesPerRow+(x/2)*2
            let yp = lumaBuffer[lumaIndex]
            let cb = chromaBuffer[chromaIndex]
            let cr = chromaBuffer[chromaIndex+1]

            let ri = Double(yp)                                + 1.402   * (Double(cr) - 128)
            let gi = Double(yp) - 0.34414 * (Double(cb) - 128) - 0.71414 * (Double(cr) - 128)
            let bi = Double(yp) + 1.772   * (Double(cb) - 128)

            let r = UInt8(min(max(ri,0), 255))
            let g = UInt8(min(max(gi,0), 255))
            let b = UInt8(min(max(bi,0), 255))
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4] = b
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4 + 1] = g
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4 + 2] = r
            rgbaImage[(x + y * width) * 4 + 3] = 255
        }
    }
    let quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer,0)
    let image = UIImage(CGImage: quartzImage!, scale: CGFloat(1.0), orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

    return (image)
    // frontCameraImageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored
    // backCameraImageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Right
}
```